# How to create a sequence on selected values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sequence, case-statement, nextval

I'm trying to create a query which will select a team from a declared variable and then make the remaining teams "anonymous" by giving them generic brands and sequential IDs.

For example, if my dataset has 3 different team names (ABC, DEF, and GHI), but I would only like the true value of the 1 chosen team (ABC) displayed.  Here is the skeleton of the query I'm working with:

```
SET @teamid = 123;

SELECT     CASE WHEN ID = @teamid
                THEN NAME
                ELSE 'Team' + ' - ' + SEQ
                END AS 'Team Name',
           SUM(TOTAL) AS 'Team Total'
FROM       TEAM
GROUP BY   1;
```

I would like the results to look something like this:

```
 Team Name:    Team Total:
 ABC           100
 Team - 1      50
 Team - 2      150
```

How can I go about creating a query which will create a unique number that I can replace the original team name with?  I know I have to replace the "SEQ" portion of the case statement, but I'm not sure what exactly to replace it with.  Also, it is important that each team has the same ID whether or not it is anonymous (so if team DEF has 50 rows, it should be shown as Team - 1 only as opposed to Team - 1-50) so that my groupings will work properly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MattBusche That's for SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: ROWNUM()...interesting, haven't thought about using that.  That would help in terms of getting a unique ID, but I was hoping more so for a means which would provide a more streamlined approach.


I can probably make a temp table and join back to the Team table and basically alter the CASE statement I had above to use the ROWNUM(), but is there anyway to eliminate that step with a sequential type of procedure.


Either way, appreciate the response.

Comment: @dupton MySQL doesn't have ROWNUM. That answer is for SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a user-defined variable that you increment. Also, MySQL uses `CONCAT` to concatenate strings, not `+`.

```
SET @teamid = 123;

SELECT     CASE WHEN ID = @teamid
                THEN NAME
                ELSE CONCAT('Team  - ', @SEQ)
                END AS 'Team Name',
           SUM(TOTAL) AS 'Team Total',
           @SEQ := CASE WHEN ID = @teamid 
                        THEN @SEQ
                        ELSE @SEQ + 1
                   END
FROM       TEAM
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @SEQ := 1) AS vars
GROUP BY   ID;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/751e4/3)

Comment: Thanks Barmar.  Noted your comment about ROWNUM() as well.  Your demo looks great (never seen that site before, really cool), but when I try it on my MySQL instance I'm returning BLOBs for both the Team Names and the SEQ column (I removed the Team Totals just to get rid of some clutter).  Any idea why that may be happening?

Comment: The `@SEQ` column can be ignored, it's just needed internally by the query. I'm not sure why you're getting blobs for the team name, though. What is the datatype of `NAME`?

Comment: The datatype of name is varchar(50).  How would I go about hiding/ignoring the SEQ portion right after the Team Total if I didn't want it included in the data?  Sorry if this is a dumb question, this is pretty new to me.

Comment: You can put this in a subquery, and then the outer query can select only the `Team Total` and `Team Name` columns.

Comment: Mentioned above that casting of the @SEQ fixed the BLOB issue, same with this query.  Thanks Barmar.

Comment: I've never needed to do that when concatenating strings with integers in MySQL, it always handles it automatically. I wonder why you need to.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The inner query aliases the team names by only incrementing the counter when the name changes. The outer one uses those names to group on.

```
SET @teamid := [the id you want];
SET @prevName := "";
SET @team_i := 0;

SELECT `Team Name`, SUM(TOTAL) AS `Team Total`
FROM (
   SELECT @team_i := @team_i + IF(@prevName <>NAME, 1, 0) AS `teamIndex`
      , @prevName := NAME AS `OriginalName`
      , IF(ID = @teamid, NAME, CONCAT('Team  - ', @team_i)) AS `Team Name`
      , TOTAL
   FROM TEAM
   ORDER BY NAME) AS subQ
GROUP BY `Team Name`;
```

and actually, it can *probably* be reversed (and this one might be slightly faster, though you do end up with extra fields in the final results):

```
SET @teamid := [the id you want];
SET @prevName := "";
SET @team_i := 0;

SELECT @team_i := @team_i + IF(@prevName <>NAME, 1, 0) AS `teamIndex`
      , @prevName := NAME AS `OriginalName`
      , IF(ID = @teamid, NAME, CONCAT('Team  - ', @team_i)) AS `Team Name`
      , `Team Total`
FROM (
   SELECT `NAME`, SUM(TOTAL) AS `Team Total`
   FROM TEAM
   GROUP BY NAME) AS subQ
ORDER BY `NAME`;
```

Comment: This looks like a good approach as well, but I'm facing the same issue as with Bamar's suggestion where the output is being shown as BLOB.  Any thoughts on why that would happen?  The Team Name datatype is a varchar(50) and I've tried casting and converting it to char, but no dice.

Comment: So it looks like I was able to fix the BLOB issue by casting the variables to a CHAR(50) and this is working perfectly.  Thanks amigo!