# Determine if date range is contained in another range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a method to do this in a "clean" way (not 3..n cross JOINS), just want to know if it's possible to do it in sql, if not I'll go for another solution.
Will use numbers instead of dates for simplification
I have n rows with n tasks and n items

```
 task  item   start end
    1     1      1     5
    1     2      2     6
    1     3      0     4
    1     4      8    10
```

In this case I'm looking to use the min(start) max(end) of the overlapping dates so the result will be:

```
task   item  start end
   1   1,2,3     0    6
   1       4     8   10
```

Any ideas of how to resolve it in sql? is like a challenge, if can't do it this way I'll go to python.

Thank you

Comment: "to do *this* in a clean way" . . . What does "this" refer to?  What is your actual question?

Comment: You'll get more help if you edit your question, and include `create table` and `insert` statements. Use dates, too.

Comment: I prefer the python idea anyway

Answer (score 0):

This similar to the problem I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337136/4104224), and similar data "island" problems. However, it is more complicated in your case as the identification of the "islands" will need to be calculated from more than just the record immediately prior.

It will end up looking something like this:

```
SET @iEnd = -1; /* init value should be something you don't expect to see */
SET @task = -1; /* init value should be something you don't expect to see */
SET @isNewIsland = 0 /* init value doesn't actually matter */;
SET @i = 0;

SELECT islandNum
   , GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item) AS items
   , MIN(start) AS iStart
   , MAX(end) AS iEnd
FROM (
    SELECT @isNewIsland := IF(@task <> task OR start > @iEnd, 1, 0)
       , @task := task, item, start, end
       , @i := IF(@isNewIsland = 1, @i + 1, @i) AS islandNum
       , @end := IF(@isNewIsland = 1, end, GREATEST(end, @iEnd))
    FROM ( /* Session(@) variables evaluation can be a bit unpredictable
              the subquery helps guarantee ordering before evaluation */
        SELECT task, item, start, end
        FROM theTable
        ORDER BY task, start, end
    ) AS subQ
) AS subQ 2
```

some are not fond of needing the separate, preceding SET statements; to avoid the need, replace `) AS subQ` with
`) AS subQ, (SELECT @iEnd := -1, @task := -1, @isNewIsland := 0, @i := 0) AS sInit`